# Where is the kernel directory for Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: kernel, directory

I need to run the following instructions:

> Run build.sh as follows from a terminal window, where
>   /path/to/expanded/folder is where build.sh is located, i.e.
>   /home/user/Desktop/ap-kernelmodule-1.0.14-13:
>
> ```
> cd /path/to/expanded/folder
>
> sudo ./build.sh --kernel-dir /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build
> ```

In my case, “the path to expanded folder” is home/sharon/savfl/ap-kernelmodule-1.0.14-13

Now, as for the kernel directory, I tried searching within almost all directories and managed to find the nearest match whose path is:

> /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0.21-generic/kernel

So, I issued the following command:

> sharon@sharon:~/savfl/ap-kernelmodule-1.0.14-13$ sudo ./build.sh
>   home/sharon/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0.21-generic/kernel
>   /lib/modules/3.5.0.21-generic/build
>
> [sudo] password for sharon:

And I got the following error message:

> Unknown Option:
>   home/sharon/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0.21-generic/kernel
>
> Usage: build.sh [options]
>
> Options:   --kernel-dir [DIRECTORY] :
>
> DIRECTORY is to set kernel headers/makefiles directory to build kernel
>   modules
>
> The default is /usr/src/kernels/3.5.0-21-generic-x86_64
>
> --kernel-rel [RELEASE]    : RELEASE is to set which kernel release
>   the kernel modules are builded for
>
> The default is the current kernel release(3.5.0-21-generic)
>
> --debug                   : Build the kernel modules with debugging
>   information
>
> --clean                   : Delete all generated files
>
> --version                 : Display the version number of the build
>   script
>
> --help                    : Display this help

Can someone help me with this please?

Please note that prior to doing the above I have installed the linux-headers relevant to my current kernel version with the following command:

> sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.5.0.21-generic build-essential

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu; hence detailed how-to instructions would be most welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Instruction source : http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH95496

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think `--kernel-dir` is not a placeholder to replace with something. It is a parameter to the build.sh to specify kernel dir. 
The kernel dir is `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build`. (The `uname -r` defines the installed kernel details.)

Try 
`sudo ./build.sh --kernel-dir /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build`

Don't alter `uname -r` with anything. It will automatically place the kernel version for the command.

Comment: @ Web-E: Thanks for your offer of help. Please click on the following link to where I got the instructions from: http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH95496

Comment: try my solution. It will work.

Comment: @ Web-E: I got the instructions from the following link: http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH95496

Comment: haha.. ok I will update my answer. BTW you don't need to replace `uname -r` by typing. It will automatically replace the kernel version. The idea was to avoid these kind of problem. Also accept the answer and delete unnecessary comments

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6871/discussion-between-web-e-and-n00b)

Comment: Upvoted. For me on Ubuntu 22.04, it is here: `/lib/modules/5.15.0-57-generic/build`